# ExtJS View properties depending on (controller-side) flag

Tags: javascript, extjs, model-view-controller

I defined a view that should be able to be called in two modes. There are only two differences depending on a flag:

- title of view (config.title)
- selectfield might be shown or hidden

Here is the simplified view:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.fancyView', {

xtype: 'fancyview',
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

config: {
    cls: 'fancyviewclass',

    title: "titleDependingOnFlag",

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            name: 'fieldsetFancy',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    itemId: 'stateID',
                    usePicker: true,
                    label: 'state',
                    store: 'States',
                    name: 'StateID',
                    valueField: 'ID',
                    displayField: 'ID'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    itemId: 'countryID',
                    usePicker: true,
                    label: 'country',
                    store: 'Countries',
                    name: 'CountryID',
                    valueField: 'ID',
                    displayField: 'ID',
                    //hidden: true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
});
```

And of course there is a controller that creates this view. At the moment I'm passing the flag as config value, see

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.fancyController', {

...
raisedBasedOnTap:function (flag){
this.myFancyFlag = !!flag;

    var myFancyView = Ext.create('FLSMOBILE.minimax.view.CallReportTimestampPlaceCar', {
        myFancyFlag: me.myFancyFlag    
    });

    app.pushView(myFancyView);

}
...
});
```

What would be the best approach to make the title depending on a flag (like title: fancyFlag? 'title1' : 'title2') and hide selectfield countryID based on the flag?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using ExtJS 5? Can you add a ViewModel to this Panel?

Comment: That means your question is about Sencha Touch and not ExtJS?